# Codeigniter Dynamic columns for Datatable with server side processing

Tags: jquery, codeigniter, datatables, server-side-rendering

CodeIgniter Server Side Processing **Dynamic Columns** not support in data tables,
I tried it with many ways

Please suggest me how we can use jQuery data table columns dynamically
 Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of resourses availabe. For view code, call the controller from jquery function like this.

```
  <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="user_data" class="display table" style="width: 100%; cellspacing: 0;">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Product title</th>
                <th>Product content</th>
                <th>Product price</th>
                <th>Product size</th>
                <th>Product qty</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Id</th>
                <th>Product title</th>
                <th>Product content</th>
                <th>Product price</th>
                <th>Product size</th>
                <th>Product qty</th>
                <th>Update</th>
                <th>Delete</th>
            </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
  </div>


<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var dataTable = $('#user_data').DataTable({
            "processing":true,
            "serverSide":true,
            "order":[],
            "ajax":{
                url:"<?php echo base_url() . 'admin_panel/fetch_product'; ?>",
                type:"POST"
            },
            "columnDefs":[
             {
                 "targets":[0, 3, 4],
                 "orderable":false,
             },
           ],
       });
</script>
```

For server Side, calling codeigniter controller function which will fecth all data from database using modal function and send it to the ajax call which will display it in the table:

```
public function fetch_product(){

    $this->load->model("crud_model"); //This will load Modal into controller
    $fetch_data = $this->crud_model->make_datatables("product",array("product_id", "product_title","product_desc","product_price","product_size","product_qty"),array("product_id", "product_title", null, null),"product_id","product_title","product_title"); // this will call modal function for fetching data
    $data = array();
    foreach($fetch_data as $row) // Loop over the data fetched and store them in array
    {
        $sub_array = array();
        $sub_array[] = $row->product_id;
        $sub_array[] = $row->product_title;
        $sub_array[] = $row->product_desc;
        $sub_array[] = $row->product_price;
        $sub_array[] = $row->product_size;
        $sub_array[] = $row->product_qty;
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="update" data-id="'.$row->product_id.'" data-option=0 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#userModal" class="edit_post btn btn-warning btn-xs">Update</button>';
        $sub_array[] = '<button type="button" name="delete" data-id="'.$row->product_id.'" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" id="d_b" class="delete_post btn btn-danger btn-xs">Delete</button>';
        $data[] = $sub_array;
    }
    $output = array(
        "draw"                    =>     intval($_POST["draw"]),
        "recordsTotal"          =>      $this->crud_model->get_all_data("product"),
        "recordsFiltered"     =>     $this->crud_model->get_filtered_data("product",array("product_id", "product_title","product_desc","product_price","product_size","product_qty"),array("product_id", "product_title", null, null),"product_id","product_title","product_title"),
        "data"                    =>     $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Now fetching data from the modal, the modal code will look something like this.

```
<?php
class Crud_model extends CI_Model
{
/*    var $table = "banner";
    var $select_column = array("banner_id", "banner_title", "banner_text", "banner_image");
    var $order_column = array("banner_id", "banner_title", "banner_text", null, null);*/


    function make_query($table,$select_column,$order_column,$where,$like,$or_like=false)
    {
        $this->db->select($select_column);
        $this->db->from($table);
        if(isset($_POST["search"]["value"]))
        {
            $this->db->like($like, $_POST["search"]["value"]);
            $this->db->or_like($or_like, $_POST["search"]["value"]);
        }
        if(isset($_POST["order"]))
        {
            $this->db->order_by($order_column[$_POST['order']['0']['column']], $_POST['order']['0']['dir']);
        }
        else
        {
            $this->db->order_by($where, 'DESC');
        }
    }
    function make_datatables($table,$select_column,$order_column,$where,$like,$or_like){
        $this->make_query($table,$select_column,$order_column,$where,$like,$or_like);
        if($_POST["length"] != -1)
        {
            $this->db->limit($_POST['length'], $_POST['start']);
        }
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_filtered_data($table,$select_column,$order_column,$where,$like,$or_like){
        $this->make_query($table,$select_column,$order_column,$where,$like,$or_like);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
    function get_all_data($table)
    {
        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->from($table);
        return $this->db->count_all_results();
    }
/*    function insert_crud($data)
    {
        $this->db->insert('users', $data);
    }*/
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, My question is I want set column/columnedef [title,width etc ] of data table dynamically not in <thead> please suggest me option for that

Comment: same way you did td dynamically, first you fetch all data from db and see the rows you want to be visible then based on that you can create anthoer array of column names and pass it along with the rows to the html.

Comment: sir, is it possible with Server Side Processing of datatable in codeigniter?

Comment: If you asking to get th tags from the server side then yes.

Comment: really thanks for quick reply , can please share me code for same, am new to CodeIgniter and jQuery, there is no reference for dynamic column with server side process in datatable